# ruby on rails sql statement error

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi guys i have a model livestream which has two columns in the database, 'user_id' and 'activity_id'. Very straight forward.

Now when I try to insert multiple records into the database I get an invalid SQL statement:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near ",": syntax error: INSERT INTO livestreams (user_id, activity_id) 
          VALUES (1, 2), (101, 2)
```

The code used to do this comes from insoshi, and is as followes:

```
def do_livestream_insert(users_ids, activity_id)
      sql = %(INSERT INTO livestreams (user_id, activity_id) 
              VALUES #{values(users_ids, activity_id)})
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
end

def values(ids, common_value)
      common_values = [common_value] * ids.length
      convert_to_sql(ids.zip(common_values))
end

def convert_to_sql(array_of_values)
      array_of_values.inspect[1...-1].gsub('[', '(').gsub(']', ')')
end
```

Why does rails do that? Does SQLlite not support the insertion of multiple records at one time?

I have reseted the database, and repopulated it.

Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Have a nice day,
Stefano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite [did not support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database) multiple records insertion until version [3.7.11](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_7_11).

Comment: how can i accomplish something like this using SQLite3? Or would you recommend using mysql instead?

Comment: The best alternative will be inserting multiple records within a single transaction (change `do_livestream_insert` appropriately). But you can surely switch to MySQL if you don't need SQLite's portability.

Comment: Version 3.7.11 of SQLite adds support for multi-row insert statements. http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest redefining do_livestream_insert to instead to N inserts

Comment: for development ok, but for production? (I am asking for your opinion)